# Adding active_storage to a Rails6 app with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-activestorage

I wanted to replace Carrierwave with ActiveStorage in a Rails 6 app that uses Mongoid as storage (and carrierwave-mongoid) but looks like this storage needs an existing Active Record setup. The `rails active_storage:install` tasks fails. I tried a mongo AR gem adapter with no luck. Is it possible to workaround it? AFAICS it needs to create 2 new tables with some attachments metadata.

Answer (score 3):

Mongoid does not include any code that is related to ActiveStorage.

Assuming ActiveStorage requires a storage backend (like ActiveRecord), and furthermore if  ActiveStorage *assumes* the application it is in uses ActiveRecord (which isn't the case for applications using Mongoid), you would need to investigate what exactly is required for AS+Mongoid integration and perform that work.

See also https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4623 where this was requested.